Data constant and always zero from the ADXL345 accelerometer with ESP32 using SPI
I am trying to get data from an ADXL345 accelerometer using an ESP32 via SPI communication. I have configured my code following the ADXL345_WE library specifications and have verified the hardware connections, but I am having trouble getting valid data from the sensor.
The problem is that even though I have correctly configured the sensor and established SPI communication, the values I get are always zero, even when I move the sensor.
...
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
DATA_END
3195 Sample(s) missed
RMS : X 0.024839    Y nan   Z 0.000000
Beginning capture.
...
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
DATA_END
3195 Sample(s) missed
RMS : X 0.024839    Y nan   Z 0.000000
Beginning capture.

Aquí está mi código:
/***************************************************************************
* Example sketch for the ADXL345_WE library
*
* This sketch shows how use SPI for the basic data sketch. Please apply the 
* same steps in the other sketches if you want to use SPI.  
*  
* Further information can be found on:
* https://wolles-elektronikkiste.de/adxl345-teil-1 (German)
* https://wolles-elektronikkiste.de/en/adxl345-the-universal-accelerometer-part-1 (English)
* 
***************************************************************************/

#include<ADXL345_WE.h>
#include<SPI.h>
#define CS_PIN 5   // Chip Select Pin

#define NUM_SAMPLES 3200

bool spi = true;    // flag indicating that SPI shall be used

xyzFloat samples[NUM_SAMPLES];
ADXL345_WE myAcc = ADXL345_WE(CS_PIN, spi);

const int int2Pin = 22;  // interrupt pin
volatile bool dataReady = false;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(921600);
  Serial.println("ADXL345 Demo");
  if(!myAcc.init()){
    Serial.println("ADXL345 not connected!");
  }

  // Prepare int pin for input
  pinMode(int2Pin, INPUT);

  /* You can set the SPI clock speed. Default is 5 MHz. */
  //  myAcc.setSPIClockSpeed(4000000);
    
  
  /* Choose the data rate         Hz
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_3200    3200
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_1600    1600
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_800      800
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_400      400
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_200      200
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_100      100
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_50        50
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_25        25
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_12_5      12.5  
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_6_25       6.25
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_3_13       3.13
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_1_56       1.56
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_0_78       0.78
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_0_39       0.39
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_0_20       0.20
      ADXL345_DATA_RATE_0_10       0.10
  */
  myAcc.setDataRate(ADXL345_DATA_RATE_3200);

  // Safety delay
  delay(100);
  Serial.print("Data rate: ");
  Serial.print(myAcc.getDataRateAsString());

  /* In full resolution the size of the raw values depend on the
      range: 2g = 10 bit; 4g = 11 bit; 8g = 12 bit; 16g =13 bit;
      uncomment to change to 10 bit for all ranges. 
  */
  // myAcc.setFullRes(false);

  /* Choose the measurement range.
      ADXL345_RANGE_16G    16g     
      ADXL345_RANGE_8G      8g     
      ADXL345_RANGE_4G      4g   
      ADXL345_RANGE_2G      2g
  */
  myAcc.setRange(ADXL345_RANGE_4G);
  Serial.print("  /  g-Range: ");
  Serial.println(myAcc.getRangeAsString());
  Serial.println();

  // Define interrupt routine and move data_ready to adxl int2
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(int2Pin), dataReadyISR, RISING);
  myAcc.setInterrupt(ADXL345_DATA_READY, INT_PIN_2); 
  myAcc.readAndClearInterrupts();

  // TODO add calibration routine
}


void loop() {

  int missed = 0;

  Serial.println("Beginning capture.");
  // Begin data acq
  for(int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_SAMPLES; cnt++) {
    // Wait for new data
    while(!dataReady) {}
    dataReady = false;
    samples[cnt] = myAcc.getGValues();
    if (dataReady) {
      // new data received before we were ready to process it => probable miss
      missed ++;
    }
  }
  Serial.println("Capture done.");

  Serial.println("Removing DC");
  processRemoveDC();

  Serial.println("DATA_START");
  Serial.println("X\tY\tZ");
  for(int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_SAMPLES; cnt++) {
    Serial.printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", samples[cnt].x,samples[cnt].y,samples[cnt].z);
  }
  Serial.println("DATA_END");
  Serial.printf("%d Sample(s) missed\n", missed);

  printRMS();
  
  delay(5000);
  
}

/* Removes the continuous (dc) component
    This will operate inplace and edit the acquired data !
*/
void processRemoveDC() {
  float meanX, meanY, meanZ = 0;
  for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_SAMPLES; cnt++) {
    meanX += samples[cnt].x;
    meanY += samples[cnt].y;
    meanZ += samples[cnt].z;
  }
  meanX /= (float) NUM_SAMPLES;
  meanY /= (float) NUM_SAMPLES;
  meanZ /= (float) NUM_SAMPLES;
  for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_SAMPLES; cnt++) {
    samples[cnt].x -= meanX;
    samples[cnt].y -= meanY;
    samples[cnt].z -= meanZ;
  }
}
/* Computes and print the RMS per axis
*/
void printRMS() {
  float rmsX, rmsY, rmsZ = 0;
  for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_SAMPLES; cnt++) {
    rmsX += pow(samples[cnt].x, 2);
    rmsY += pow(samples[cnt].y, 2);
    rmsZ += pow(samples[cnt].z, 2);
  }
  rmsX = sqrt(rmsX/(float)NUM_SAMPLES);
  rmsY = sqrt(rmsY/(float)NUM_SAMPLES);
  rmsZ = sqrt(rmsZ/(float)NUM_SAMPLES);

  Serial.printf("RMS : X %f\tY %f\tZ %f\n", rmsX, rmsY, rmsZ);
}

void dataReadyISR(){
  dataReady = true;
}

Here is my wiring:

Here's my realization:

I have tried debugging the code and checking the hardware connections, but have not been able to find the problem. Is there something I am overlooking or any settings I need to adjust to get valid data from the sensor?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanks!
Update with simpler example
I tried with this tutorial with less connections and code:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADXL345_U.h>
  
/*Initialize an instance of Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified with a unique id*/
Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified accel = Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified(12345);
 
void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Small example to read from ADXL345 accelerometer");
   
}
 
void loop() {
   
  /*Read from ADXL345 accelerometer*/
  sensors_event_t event; 
  accel.getEvent(&event);
 
  /* Display the results (acceleration is measured in m/s^2) */
  Serial.print("X: "); Serial.print(event.acceleration.x); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("Y: "); Serial.print(event.acceleration.y); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("Z: "); Serial.print(event.acceleration.z); Serial.print("  ");Serial.println("m/s^2 ");
  /*Take a one second break*/
  delay(1000);
 
}

But now got a problem reading or accessing an invalid memory address:
A10     : 0x3ffc1e70  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x00000000  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x40086244  LEND    : 0x4008624f  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x400d1c54:0x3ffb2170 0x400d1c8e:0x3ffb2190 0x400d1cb5:0x3ffb21b0 0x400d18b1:0x3ffb21d0 0x400d18c1:0x3ffb2200 0x400d1912:0x3ffb2220 0x400d14dc:0x3ffb2240 0x400d4281:0x3ffb2290




ELF file SHA256: 5143f7db4d6401a9

Rebooting...

�
Small example to read from ADXL345 accelerometer
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d1c57  PS      : 0x00060230  A0      : 0x800d1c91  A1      : 0x3ffb2170  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x00000000  
A6      : 0x3ffb833c  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x3ffb22b0  A9      : 0x3ffb2290  
A10     : 0x3ffc1e70  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x00000000  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000001d  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x40086244  LEND    : 0x4008624f  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x400d1c54:0x3ffb2170 0x400d1c8e:0x3ffb2190 0x400d1cb5:0x3ffb21b0 0x400d18b1:0x3ffb21d0 0x400d18c1:0x3ffb2200 0x400d1912:0x3ffb2220 0x400d14dc:0x3ffb2240 0x400d4281:0x3ffb2290
�


Which tutorial are you following? This one? https://www.electronicwings.com/esp32/adxl345-accelerometer-interfacing-with-esp32

No, but thanks for mentioning it @tepalia I am following this one
